# how to do a 3 filters from a <select> in ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

im a fairly newbie into javascript and php (just got less than two weeks max)however im trying to learn because i really enjoy this,anyway, right now im trying to do a proyect for the company where i work for ( not that we will use it, but as an incentive).

the proyect is about making a query  in sql that would return a table, but using  the parameters given in three  drop down's
now those three 's must pick three conditionals. ie

```
 $sql ="SELECT * FROM catalogo WHERE escuelas='$e' and grado='$g' and seccion='$p'";
```

so far i have wrote ( and to be honest copy/paste a lot from different sources)
the basics, but im stuck trying to a query.. anyway here is my code for the  index.php

```
<script>
        function showescuelas(str) {
            if (str == "") {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
                return;
            } else { 
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                } else {
                    // code for IE6, IE5
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    }
                }
                xmlhttp.open("GET","ajaxdatospersonales.php?e="+str, true);
               //xmlhttp.open("GET","ajaxdatospersonales.php?e="+document.getElementById("esc").value+"&gra="+document.getElementById("gra").value+"&sec="+document.getElementById("sec").value,,true);

                xmlhttp.send();
            }
        }
        </script>
        </header>
        <?php include_once("menu.php"); ?>
        <div class="container">
           <h1> Agregar apartado </h1>
        <form id="form" method="post" action="procesadordatospersonales.php" >


          <!-- down below is my first filter, it feeds from a table named "escuelas"-->
            <p> <label for="escuelas">Escuela:</label>
               <select name="escuelas"  id="esc" onchange="showescuelas(this.value)">
                echo "<option>  </option>";
                <?php
                    $con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'pass') or die(mysql_error());
                    mysql_select_db('apartados');

                    $sql = "SELECT escuelas FROM escuelas";
                    $data = mysql_query($sql,$con);

                    while($category = mysql_fetch_array($data)){
                        $catname = $category['escuelas'];
                        $valueid = $category['escuelas'];
                      echo '<option value="'.$valueid.'">'.$catname.'</option>';
                    }
                ?>

                </select>

                <br />

            </p>





          <!-- down below is my second filter, it feeds from a table named "grados"-->

            <p> <label for="grado">grado:</label>
               <select name="grado"  id="gra" onChange="showgrados(this.value)">
                echo "<option>  </option>";
                <?php
                    $con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'pass') or die(mysql_error());
                    mysql_select_db('apartados');

                    $sql = "SELECT grado FROM grado";
                    $data = mysql_query($sql,$con);

                    while($category = mysql_fetch_array($data)){
                        $catname = $category['grado'];
                        $valueid = $category['grado'];
                      echo '<option value="'.$valueid.'">'.$catname.'</option>';
                    }
                ?>

                </select>

                <br />




            </p>
         <!-- yep you guess it this is the last  filter, it feeds from a table named "grados"-->

            <p> <label for="seccion" >seccion:</label>
               <select name="seccion" id="sec" onChange="showescuelas(this.value)">
                echo "<option>  </option>";
                <?php
                    $con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'pass') or die(mysql_error());
                    mysql_select_db('apartados');

                    $sql = "SELECT seccion FROM seccion";
                    $data = mysql_query($sql,$con);

                    while($category = mysql_fetch_array($data)){
                        $catname = $category['seccion'];
                        $valueid = $category['seccion'];
                      echo '<option value="'.$valueid.'">'.$catname.'</option>';
                    }
                ?>

                </select>

                <br />




            </p>

        </div>
        </div>

        <div id="txtHint"><b> info will be listed here.</b></div>

            <input type="submit" value="Agregar">
        </form>
```

and this is my "ajaxdatospersonales.php"

```
<?php
                $e=$_GET["e"];
                $g=$_GET["g"];
                $s=$_GET["s"];


                $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','pass','apartados');
                if (!$con)
                  {
                  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
                  }
                mysqli_select_db($con);



                //i made this array just to check if the variables 
                $test= array("$e", "$g", "$s"); 
                echo "esta es la escuela " . $test[0] . " y este el grado " . $test[1] . " y la seccion " . $test[2] . ".";



                $sql ="SELECT * FROM catalogo WHERE escuelas='$e' and grado='$g' and seccion='$p'";


                $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
                $ii=1;
                echo "<table border='1'>
                <tr>
                <th>agregar</th>
                <th>isbn</th>
                <th>nombre</th>
                <th>autor</th>
                <th>editorial</th>
                </tr>";

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                  {
                  echo "<tr>";
                  echo "<td> <input type='checkbox' name= isbn".$ii." value=".$row['isbn']. " </td>";
                  echo "<td>" . $row['isbn'] . "</td>";
                  echo "<td>" . $row['nombre'] . "</td>";
                  echo "<td>" . $row['autor'] . "</td>";
                  echo "<td>" . $row['editorial'] . "</td>";
                  echo "</tr>";
                  $ii++;
                  }
                echo "</table>";

                mysqli_close($con);
                ?>
```

now for some reaso it just dosent work.... i dont know whats going on..
thanks.

now if you decide to help me please, try to be as newbie frendly as possible.
also i already know about sql injection. but this is a proyect for fun

Comment: a fiddle would be appreciable

Comment: Take a look at your developer console in the browser, you can see how the requests are made (eg to what URL) and what is returned. This can help alot in debugging ajax requests

Comment: Even if the project is for fun, you should NEVER use $_GET variables to query your database.

Comment: i could show you a live page.

Comment: -ReferenceError: showescuelas is not defined-
you should definitely check your developer's console as @kingkero said!

Comment: for solving the sql injection i should add: mysql_real_escape_string right?

Comment: @juancarlos I would rather switch to PDO instead, and use prepared statements!

Comment: @enjoyted i would definitly would read about PDO later on.  thanks for the help